# Firestore query for a rule with "hasOnly"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, rules

I have a Firestore Rule, where if the "businesses" array of the custom claim token of a user auth contains all the items in "businessIds" field of a document (which is an array), the user is supposed to be allowed to read and write that document, as following:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read, write: if resource.data.businessIds.hasOnly(request.auth.token.businesses);
}
```

However this rule doesn't allow read/write any documents. Here is my test:

```
it("Allows a marketeer to read all its users", async () => {
  ...
  const mp1UserId = "MP1_user_crm";
  const mp1Doc = admin.collection("users").doc(mp1UserId);
  await mp1Doc.set({displayName: "MP CRMer for MP1", type: "MP CRMer", businessIds: ["MP1_ID"]});
  const marketeerAuth = {uid: "marketeer_user", businesses: ["MP1_ID", "MP2_ID"]};
  const db = base.getFirestore(marketeerAuth);
  const testRead = db.collection("users")
  .where("businessIds", "array-contains-any", marketeerAuth.businesses);
  var all = testRead.get();
  await base.firebase().assertSucceeds(all); // FAILS HERE
});
```

I cannot find a way to write a query that satisfies the rule. There is apparently no operator for [**hasOnly()**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasOnly) in [firebase.firestore.WhereFilterOp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore#wherefilterop).

Note that it complains about **hasOnly**:

```
FirebaseError: 
false for 'list' @ L59, Function not found error: Name: [hasOnly]. for 'list' @ L136
```

How can I write a query that can pass the security rule?

---

**UPDATE:**

I'm asked to explain what's in "request.auth.token.businesses". Auth with its custom claim token are as following (which can be also constructed in Rule Playground too):

```
"auth": {
  "uid": "marketeer_user"
  "token": {
    "sub": ""
    "aud": "hanOnly-sandbox"
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "custom"
    }
    "businesses": [
      "MP1_ID",
      "MP2_ID",
    ]
  }
}
```

In "resource.data.businessIds" data are as the following database structure:

[image]

Comment: Before concluding that hasOnly() cannot be used, I would need to see the content of both lists: "resource.data.businessIds" and "request.auth.token.businesses". Could you please show the content to see what is being compared?

Comment: @acarrion I've update the question with content of "resource.data.businessIds" and "request.auth.token.businesses". If more information is needed please let me know.

Comment: If you try with: `if resource.data.businessIds.hasOnly(["MP1_ID", "MP2_ID"]);` do you get the same error?

Comment: @Sergi Yes, I get the very same error

Comment: Review it again I think in this case I would try better with `hasAll()` instead of `hasOnly()`. If it doesn't work then you can try with a [custom function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions)

Comment: @Sergi the logic `hasAll()` gives different results from `hasOnly()`. I cannot use the one that is not suitable for my case. I am aware of `custom functions` and they don't make any difference in this instance.